# How to explode string in php by float numbers

Tags: php

My question is that i have an string like

> Pi number is 3,14 \n Pi number is not 3,20

and i want to make this string into

```
[0] = Pi number is
[1] = 3,14
[2] = Pi number is not
[3] = 3,20
```

is there any way to do it? im a little confused

Comment: You should see [Regex](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php). That's what you need

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want to split at every integer. `preg_split` can be used for this:

```
preg_split('/(\d+(?:,\d+)?)/', 'Pi number is 3,14 \n Pi number is not 3,20', -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE)
```

- `\d` is a number
- `()` is a capture group
- `?:` is a non-capture group (tell the regex engine not to waste resources capturing something that won't be used)
- stand alone `?` makes the previous group/character optional

https://3v4l.org/fnZMF